# Angular Observable BehaviourSubject.getValue() returns normal value

Tags: angular, observable, return-value

I have this syntax:

```
const pageId = this._someService.currentData$<Data>().getValue().id;
```

which returns a normal string value with `getValue()` from the Observable (BehaviourSubject) `currentPage$<Page>()`. The class BehaviousSubject implements  the getValue() method

```
export declare class BehaviorSubject<T> extends Subject<T> {
getValue(): T;
}
```

but how is that possible? I thought we have to subscribe to an observable to get the actual value.. ?

Comment: Don't mistake `Observables` for `Subjects`, they are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

```
   private deviceType = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  currentDeviceType = this.deviceType.asObservable();
  changeDeviceType(value: string) {
    this.deviceType.next(value);
  }
```

This is how you can make a subject an Observable and the function to change the value, so now you can subscribe to the currentDeviceType and get all the value changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple types of `Observable`s, most of them do not hold the value, but some of them do.

The examples that hold values are `BehaviorSubject` and `ReplaySubject`.

`BehaviorSubject` requires a value in the constructor. It implements all methods of `Observable` as well as `Subject`, but it has its own special `value` and `getValue` properties.

`ReplaySubject` will reply X (provided in the constructor) number of the last emissions upon subscription. Passing `1` will make it almost into a `BehaviorSubject`.

### Why?

If you need some variable to be observable, but you sometimes need it immediately (synchronously), you make it into a `BehaviorSubject`. You don't have to expose it as `BehaviorSubject`, you could expose only the `Observable` or `Subject` of it.

```
class LoginService {
  private readonly _isLoggiedIn$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  public readonly isLoggiedIn$ = this._isLoggiedIn$ as Subject<boolean>;
}
```